# SQL Server Select and Group by datediff

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to group by a product and return the average time they are being used based on a datediff function.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT products.productNameCommon, datediff(minute,history.timeOut, history.timeIn) as session
FROM FlexLM_history history
JOIN FlexLM_products products ON products.productID=history.productID
where products.productType = 'base' and history.timeIn is Not NULL
GROUP BY products.productNameCommon, datediff(minute,history.timeOut, history.timeIn)
ORDER BY products.productNameCommon
```

My results are like this:

```
productNameCommon | avgSession
----------------- | ----------
Product 1         | 5
Product 1         | 15
Product 1         | 40
Product 2         | 2
Product 2         | 5
Product 3         | 12
Product 3         | 24
```

What I really need is this:

```
productNameCommon | avgSession
----------------- | ----------
Product 1         | 20
Product 2         | 3.5
Product 3         | 18
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `datediff()` from the `GROUP BY` and wrap the `datediff()` in `sum()` in your column selection?  ie: sum(datediff())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub query and average

```
SELECT Q.ProductNameCommon, AvgSession = AVG(Session) FROM
( --Your query
    SELECT products.productNameCommon, datediff(minute,history.timeOut, history.timeIn) as Session
    FROM FlexLM_history history
    JOIN FlexLM_products products ON products.productID=history.productID
    where products.productType = 'base' and history.timeIn is Not NULL
    GROUP BY products.productNameCommon, datediff(minute,history.timeOut, history.timeIn)
) as Q
group by Q.ProductNameCommon
order by Q.ProductNameCommon
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ABC.productNameCommon, AVG(Session) as avgSession
FROM
(
    SELECT products.productNameCommon, datediff(minute,history.timeOut, history.timeIn) as Session
    FROM FlexLM_history history
    JOIN FlexLM_products products ON products.productID=history.productID
    where products.productType = 'base' and history.timeIn is Not NULL
    GROUP BY products.productNameCommon, datediff(minute,history.timeOut, history.timeIn)
) as ABC
    GROUP BY ABC.productNameCommon  --miss this line before
    ORDER BY ABC.productNameCommon
```

Comment: Almost right. Just missing the `GROUP BY ABC.productNameCommon`